# Custom transformer for sklearn Pipeline that alters both X and y

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to create my own transformer for use with the sklearn `Pipeline`.

I am creating a class that implements both fit and transform methods. The purpose of the transformer will be to remove rows from the matrix that have more than a specified number of NaNs.

The issue I am facing is **how can I change both the X and y matrices that are passed to the transformer?**

I believe this has to be done in the fit method since it has access to both X and y. Since python passes arguments by assignment once I reassign X to a new matrix with fewer rows the reference to the original X is lost (and of course the same is true for y). Is it possible to maintain this reference?

I’m using a pandas DataFrame to easily drop the rows that have too many NaNs, this may not be the right way to do it for my use case. The current code looks like this:

```
class Dropna():

    # thresh is max number of NaNs allowed in a row
    def __init__(self, thresh=0):
        self.thresh = thresh

    def fit(self, X, y):
        total = X.shape[1]
        # +1 to account for 'y' being added to the dframe                                                                                                                            
        new_thresh = total + 1 - self.thresh
        df = pd.DataFrame(X)
        df['y'] = y
        df.dropna(thresh=new_thresh, inplace=True)
        X = df.drop('y', axis=1).values
        y = df['y'].values
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Modifying the sample axis, e.g. removing samples, does not (yet?) comply with the scikit-learn transformer API. So if you need to do this, you should do it outside any calls to scikit learn, as preprocessing.

As it is now, the transformer API is used to transform the features of a given sample into something new. This can implicitly contain information from other samples, but samples are never deleted.

Another option is to attempt to impute the missing values. But again, if you need to delete samples, treat it as preprocessing before using scikit learn.

Answer (score 9):

You have to modify the internal code of sklearn `Pipeline`.

We define a transformer that removes samples where at least the value of a feature or the target is NaN during fitting (`fit_transform`). While it removes the samples where at least the value of a feature is NaN during inference (`transform`). Important to note that **our transformer returns X and y in `fit_transform`** so we need to handle this behaviour in the sklearn `Pipeline`.

```
class Dropna():

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def fit_transform(self, X, y):
        
        mask = (np.isnan(X).any(-1) | np.isnan(y))
        if hasattr(X, 'loc'):
            X = X.loc[~mask]
        else:
            X = X[~mask]
        if hasattr(y, 'loc'):
            y = y.loc[~mask]
        else:
            y = y[~mask]
        
        return X, y   ###### make fit_transform return X and y
    
    def transform(self, X):
        
        mask = np.isnan(X).any(-1)
        if hasattr(X, 'loc'):
            X = X.loc[~mask]
        else:
            X = X[~mask]
        
        return X
```

We only have to modify the original sklearn `Pipeline` in only two specific points in `fit` and in `_fit` method. The rest remains unchanged.

```
from sklearn import pipeline
from sklearn.base import clone
from sklearn.utils import _print_elapsed_time
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_memory

class Pipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def _fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params_steps):
        self.steps = list(self.steps)
        self._validate_steps()
        memory = check_memory(self.memory)

        fit_transform_one_cached = memory.cache(pipeline._fit_transform_one)

        for (step_idx, name, transformer) in self._iter(
            with_final=False, filter_passthrough=False
        ):
                        
            if transformer is None or transformer == "passthrough":
                with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(step_idx)):
                    continue

            try:
                # joblib >= 0.12
                mem = memory.location
            except AttributeError:
                mem = memory.cachedir
            finally:
                cloned_transformer = clone(transformer) if mem else transformer

            X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
                cloned_transformer,
                X,
                y,
                None,
                message_clsname="Pipeline",
                message=self._log_message(step_idx),
                **fit_params_steps[name],
            )
            
            if isinstance(X, tuple):    ###### unpack X if is tuple: X = (X,y)
                X, y = X
            
            self.steps[step_idx] = (name, fitted_transformer)
        
        return X, y
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
        Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
        
        if isinstance(Xt, tuple):    ###### unpack X if is tuple: X = (X,y)
            Xt, y = Xt 
        
        with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
            if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
                fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
                self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)

        return self
```

This is required in order to unpack the values generated by `Dropna().fit_transform(X, y)` in the new `X` and `y`.

Here is the full pipeline at work:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,3))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,))
X[np.random.uniform(0,1, (100)) < 0.1] = np.nan
y[np.random.uniform(0,1, (100)) < 0.1] = np.nan

pipe = Pipeline([('dropna', Dropna()), ('model', Ridge())])
pipe.fit(X, y)

pipe.predict(X).shape
```

Another trial with a further intermediate preprocessing step:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipe = Pipeline([('dropna', Dropna()), ('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('model', Ridge())])
pipe.fit(X, y)

pipe.predict(X).shape
```

More complex behaviors can be achieved with other simple modifications according to the needs. If you are interested also in `Pipeline().fit_transform` or `Pipeline().fit_predict` you need to operate the same changes.

Comment: This is an amazing answer and allows so much more flexibility in pipelines. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The package `imblearn`, which is built on top of `sklearn`, contains an estimator [FunctionSampler](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.FunctionSampler.html#functionsampler) that allows manipulating both the features array, `X`, and target array, `y`, in a pipeline step.

Note that using it in a pipeline step requires using the `Pipeline` class in `imblearn` that inherits from the one in `sklearn`. Furthermore, by default, in the context of `Pipeline`, the method `resample` does nothing when it is not called immediately after `fit` (as in `fit_resample`). So, read the documentation ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @João Matias response:

Here's an example of using imblearn to define a pipeline step that drops rows with missing values:

```
from imblearn import FunctionSampler
def drop_rows_with_any_nan(X, y):
    return X[~np.isnan(X).any(axis=1), :], y[~np.isnan(X).any(axis=1)]
drop_rows_with_any_nan_sampler = FunctionSampler(func=drop_rows_with_any_nan, validate=False)
model_clf2 = pipeline.Pipeline(
    [
        ('preprocess', column_transformer),
        ('drop_na', drop_rows_with_any_nan_sampler),
        ('smote', SMOTE()),
        ('xgb', xgboost.XGBClassifier()),
    ]
)
```

Note, you have to use the imblearn pipeline.

Comment: Problem with this solution seems to be that the sampling only takes place when executing .transform(), but not when executing .predict()...? This is due to the fact that imblearn's Pipeline only resamples during fit but not during inference.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this easily by using the sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer method (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html)

You just need to put your alternations to X in a function

```
def drop_nans(X, y=None):
    total = X.shape[1]                                           
    new_thresh = total - thresh
    df = pd.DataFrame(X)
    df.dropna(thresh=new_thresh, inplace=True)
    return df.values
```

then you get your transformer by calling

```
transformer = FunctionTransformer(drop_nans, validate=False)
```

which you can use in the pipeline. The threshold can be set outside the drop_nans function.

Answer (score 0):

@eickenberg is the proper and clean answer. Nevertheless, I like to keep everything into one Pipeline, so if you are interested, I created a library (not yet deployed on pypi) that allow to apply transformation on Y:

https://gitlab.com/thibaultB/transformers/

Usage is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
df.columns = ["a", "b", "target"]

spliter = SplitXY("target") # Create a new step and give it name of column target

pipe = Pipeline([
        ("imputer", SklearnPandasWrapper(KNNImputer())),
        ("spliter", spliter), 
        ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
        ("rf",
            EstimatorWithoutYWrapper(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=45),
                                    spliter)) # EstimatorWithoutYWrapper overwrite RandomForestRegressor to get y from spliter just before calling fit or transform
    ])
pipe.fit(df)

res = pipe.predict(df)
```

Using this code, you can alter the number of rows if you put all the transformer that modify the numbers of rows before the "SplitXY" transformer. Transformer before the SplitXY transformer should keep columns name, it is why I also added a SklearnPandasWrapper that wrap sklearn transformer (that usually return numpy array) to keep columns name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `function transformer`

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[np.NaN,np.NaN,9],[7,np.NaN,9]])
```

[image]

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FunctionTransformer,make_pipeline

def remove_na(df_,thresh=2):
    return df.dropna(thresh=2)

pipe=make_pipeline(FunctionTransformer(func=remove_na,
                                       validate=False,kw_args={"thresh":2}))
pipe.fit_transform(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use "*deep-copies*" further on, down the pipeline and **`X`**, **`y`** remain protected

**`.fit()`** can first assign on each call *deep-copy* to new class-variables

```
self.X_without_NaNs = X.copy()
self.y_without_NaNs = y.copy()
```

and then reduce / transform these not to have more `NaN`-s than ordered by `self.treshold`

Comment: But how are other transformers in the same pipeline suppose to access these copies?

Comment: This is an incomplete solution, it does not address the problem and leave extra doubts about it.