# Labels (y) in Scikit-learn Pipeline and Compose Classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, data-transform

My current understanding is that, we cant directly transform/retrieve `y-labels` passed as `(X,y)` while using a Pipeline.

The `fit_transform` at the end returns transformations only on the `X` passed and `y` is only utilized in situations involving `fit()`, `fit_predict()` and such.

Is my understanding correct?

Also is there a way to transform and retrieve `y` (including when dropping instances using a Custom Transformer) without having to break out of a fully enclosed model training pipeline?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70191787/10375049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, your understanding is correct. `Pipeline` objects are meant for sequential application of several transformations of `X`. From the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipelines-and-composite-estimators):

> **Pipelines only transform the observed data (`X`).**

Also have a look at the [gloassary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-transform) about the term transform:

> **transform**
> In a transformer, transforms the input, **usually only `X`**, into some transformed space (conventionally notated as `Xt`).

In case of a regression tasks, there is a special [`TransformedTargetRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html#sklearn-compose-transformedtargetregressor) which deals with transforming the target `y` and can e.g. be used at the end of a pipeline.

Other than that, there is no canonical way in controlling transformations of `y` in a pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So just to be certain, if am to use a LabelEncoder or a CustomTransformer to remove certain instances(X and y), I would have to do it outside a pipeline performing other tasks. @afsharov .

Comment: @AkD that's right. If you need to drop samples, it should be done before fitting the pipeline. Same goes for encodings of `y`.