# using scikit-learn preprocesser to select subset of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a scikit-learn preprocesser I can use or implement to select a subset of rows from a pandas dataframe? I would prefer a preprocesser to do this since I want to build a pipeline with this as a step.

Comment: This can be done with pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe. Are you selecting rows based on some criteria?

Comment: yes, I do have a criteria and I want to use a preprocesser rather than pandas

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539311/custom-transformer-for-sklearn-pipeline-that-alters-both-x-and-y you should probably do it outside of `sklearn`. Can you just make a custom function to drop offending rows and insert it into your pipeline? Without some more context or example code, I don't think I can offer anything more helpful.

Comment: As mentioned in an answer at the linked question above, the `imblearn` package extends the `sklearn` pipeline to accommodate changing the number of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `FunctionTransformer` to do that. To a FunctionTransformer, you can pass any Callable that exposes the same interface as standard scikitlearn transform calls have. In code

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

class RowSelector:
    def __init__(self, rows:list[int]):
        self._rows = rows

    def __call__(self, X:pd.DataFrame, y=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return X.iloc[self._rows,:]

selector = FunctionTransformer(RowSelector(rows=[1,3]))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4), 'b':range(4), 'c':range(4)})
selector.fit_transform(df)
#Returns
   a  b  c
1  1  1  1
3  3  3  3
```

Not that, I have used a callable object to track some state, i.e. the rows to be selected. This is not necessary and could be solved differently.

The cool thing is that it returns a data frame, so if you have it as the first step of your pipeline, you can also combine it with a subsequent column transformer (if needed of course)