# sklearn pipelines and filtering out records?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

I have been trying to come up with a transformer for the `sklearn` `Pipeline` architecture that actually filters and removes records meeting certain criteria in the course of the pipeline - a `WHERE` clause, if you will. I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24897058/717481) that says "any transformer that drops or adds samples is, as of the existing versions of scikit-learn, not compliant with the API", but it is from 7 years ago. Have things changed, and if not, what is a good statement of the `Pipeline` philosophy that explains why removing records does not fit with its concepts? (I definitely get why adding samples doesn't make sense, and I *think* I get why removing might not, but I'd like to read the official reasons for this in order to better grasp the thinking around the API.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is still valid as of today.

I am not aware of any "official" statement in the documentation of `scikit-learn` that addresses this issue or justifies this design choice. However, I believe the main reason this is not supported is the fact that `Pipeline` objects only transform `X`. At least for this, there is a [source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipelines-and-composite-estimators):

> Pipelines only transform the observed data (`X`).

In consequence, if you would drop or add any samples to `X`, the number of samples would become inconsistent with `y`. I think this is the most likely reason for this design choice.

That being said, the pipeline implementation of `imblearn` does in fact allow transformations that change the sample size as it allows to include resamplers in the pipeline (see [here](http://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#imblearn-pipeline-pipeline)). However, this is restricted to sampling methods that comply with the `imblearn` API methods only.